# How to add an external javascript file to a Zend Framework 2 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need to add jQuery and other javascript files to my Zend Framework project. I am trying to do it with an Action controller:-

```
public function userinfoAction()
{   
    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile($basePath .'/js/validate_jquary.js');
    $this->headScript()->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'); 
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Are you echoing `$this->headScript()` in your layout or view? Also, the fact that you have a return statement in your action doesn't look right to me, although I'm not familiar with ZF2, so it may be valid.

Comment: @ vascowhite: I was ecoho `$this->headScript()` in the controller.

Comment: You shouldn't be echoing anything in the controller, that breaks MVC. You should do that in the view or layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 $this->HeadScript()->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js','text/javascript');
 $this->HeadScript()->appendFile('http://localhost/zend/public/js/validate_jquary.js','text/javascript');
```

It is OK with this code in the view. But I don't know is this correct method.

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you can use view helpers *from within a controller* in ZF2 to solve your problem:

```
public function someAction()
{                 
     $this->getViewHelper('HeadScript')->appendFile($basePath . '/js/somejs.js');    
}

protected function getViewHelper($helperName)
{
    return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get($helperName);
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving the example from the controller. It feels dirty adding scripts and styles from the view, but it seems many examples of ZF2 suggests this is ok. Which one is considered the "correct" way of adding scripts/styles?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way to use view helpers from within a controller in ZF2 is via the renderer object:

```
public function someAction()
{                 
     $renderer = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');
     $renderer->headScript()->appendFile($renderer->baseUrl() . '/js/somejs.js');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this. its works fine for me

//write these lines in your SampleController

```
public function someAction()
{

$this->getViewHelper('HeadScript')->appendFile('/js/yourjsfile.js');
$this->getViewHelper('HeadScript')->appendFile('/js/jquery/jquery.min.js');
}
```

// write following method in controller

```
protected function getViewHelper($helperName)
{

    return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get($helperName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the view to add jquery:

```
 $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

a good way for that is to use the below code in your controller action
lets say u want to include the  paginator.js

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/js/paginator.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the above is giving tons of errors for me and $this->view->headScript() is at all about Zend Framework 1. This works for me:

in your controller before controller's class definition add:

```
use Zend\View\Helper\HeadScript;
```

and then you may use something like this in your controller (sure you may use it in any action, not only in the constructor):

```
/**
 * @var Zend\View\Helper\HeadScript
 */
protected $headScript;

function __construct() {
    $this->headScript = new HeadScript();
    $this->headScript->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js','text/javascript');
}
```

and then you should add this to your layout:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
```