# Zend 2:: getting public folder path or basePath() easily in controller action

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In my application, to move a file to a specific directory i need to know public folder path in controller action. I read different this type solution but not getting easy one. I know that in view we can get easily public folder path using `$this->basePath();` view helper. I exactly want this in controller action. Anybody can guide me how can i achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

`index.php` sets the current working dir to you application root (the folder containing `composer.json`, `init_autoloader.php`, etc.)

As long as you haven't called `chdir` elsewhere in your application you can call `getcwd()` and it'll always return the path to your app root.

Since the public folder is relative to that, you can get the path using ...

```
$publicDir = getcwd() . '/public';
```

Answer (score 3):

In your public folder edit your file named index.php
add only two lines

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__DIR__)));
define('PUBLIC_PATH', BASE_PATH.'/public');
```

you can use in your code like

```
print_r(BASE_PATH);
print_r(PUBLIC_PATH);
```

Comment: You saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use view helpers from within a controller in ZF2 as it shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346952/how-to-add-an-external-javascript-file-to-a-zend-framework-2-application/13644702#13644702) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642275/zend-framework-2-base-path-access-in-controller). You may try this for your case :

```
$renderer = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');
$url = $renderer->basePath('the_ressource_you_want_to_get_from_public_folder');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a file from public folder (independence with location of index.php file):
include_one ("./public/your-file.php");

Answer (score 0):

You should try this if you want the public folder:

```
$publicPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Or try this if you want the basepath:

```
$basePath = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```