# zendframework 2 how do i upload images to a directory in my view

Tags: zend-framework2

i have a quick question and would really appropriate some advice.

i am trying to upload images to a directory held in in the view of a module.

**the full link to the pic's directory in 'my member's module' is:**

```
C:/Users/test/zend/testingZend2/module/Members/view/members/pics
```

however, the upload function is held in MembersController :

```
C:/Users/test/zend/testingZend2/module/Members/src/Members/Controller/membersController
```

i am able to upload images to the directory. however, i obviously don't want to use the **full URL**. i want to use a **relative link**.

i tried the relative links below but they don't work;

```
 Members/view/members/pics
```

and

```
../../../view/members/pics
```

is there for example a function like dirname(**DIR**) that will provide the first half of the link to the pics directory.

thank you for your help

Comment: try this please getcwd() or __DIR__ and then you can play around a crate your route

Comment: hi dixromos98. Thank you for your response. can you please clarify. how would i use them?

Comment: well if you echo getcwd() inside a controller you will get the root path. if you echo __DIR__ inside a controller you will get the current modules path, so i guess you can cut off the part you don't need with explode() and add the path you want. But i asked you to try because i never used zend locally so i dont know what that will give you so that is why im asking you to try :)

Comment: It's the same as this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/23721616/1112089 use `getcwd()` to get your app root, and append your relative path `/module/Members/view/members/pics` to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths are relative to the application root, so `module/Members/view/members/pics` should work.

I would question whether the view folder is a sensible place to store user-uploaded images. Images aren't views, and you won't be able to display these images easily since they are not in a public folder.

Comment: Hello Tim. should the images then be placed in the public folder

Comment: The reason why i ask Tim is that samUser,in an earlier question, said that its not right for users to upload images to the public folder.

Comment: It depends a bit what the images are for, and who your users are (i.e. are they completely anonymous, or logged in users?). If they're logged in I'd say a sub-folder of `public/` is fine for the ultimate destination. Otherwise `data/` might be more appropriate.

Comment: hi Tim. thanks so much for your response. i really appreciate all the help you have given thus far; quick question, when you say that it depends on whether they are logged in or not; does that mean that the public folder is not as secure as another location in the framework?

Comment: I don't want to send you down the wrong path here, it really depends on your use case. But if you allow anyone who visits your website (i.e. anonymous users) to upload any image, the feature will be abused.

Comment: Hi Tim. i just wanted to personally thank you for your kind advice. You have been brilliant.